# Why it took so long for Israel to build the Temple and establish the state?

Tags: moses, temple, solomon

Israel couldn't build the Temple since exodus from Egypt until the time of Solomon - for about 300 years.
Almost as much time it took to establish the kingdom in the promised land. Is there any particular reason generations of Israelites were unable to do so? Why God didn't want Israel to have a state and the Temple?
If God spoke (2 Chronicles 6: 5-6)  and didn't give any reason for this, are there any speculations for why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take the two parts of the question separately.

**1. Building the temple**

It is true that the construction of the first temple took many years.  Indeed, we have this recorded in 1 Kings 6:1 -

> In the four hundred and eightieth year after the Israelites had come
> out of the land of Egypt, in the month of Ziv, the second month of the
> fourth year of Solomon’s reign over Israel, he began to build the
> house of the LORD.

However, before this time, the original tabernacle existed and provided all the functions that the temple did.  The only differences were:

- the temple was a permanent structure in a fixed location (The tabernacle had at least two locations before the temple was built)
- the temple was far more magnificent and expensive than the "tent" of the tabernacle

However, nothing about the religion nor the ritual associated with the temple/tabernacle changed when the temple was built.

A more interesting question might be - Why did it take so long to build a permanent structure of the temple?  That is more difficult to answer.

However, it is likely that

- the permanent temple had to wait until the monarchy was established so have enough concentrated wealth (in the king) to finance such an endeavor
- the location for the temple was within the city of Jerusalem which, until David captured the Jebusite capital about 1000 BC (2 Sam 5), soon after David is crowned, was unavailable land.  The temple site was the same place that Abraham almost sacrificed Isaac.

**2. Israel as a State**

It is a mistake to think that Israel only became a state when the Israelite monarch was established.  Indeed, we have this declaration of Israel as a nation before they even reached the promised land -

> Ex 19:5, 6 - Now if you will indeed obey My voice and keep My
> covenant, you will be My treasured possession out of all the
> nations—for the whole earth is Mine. And unto Me you shall be a
> **kingdom of priests** and a **holy nation**.’

Now, between the death of Joshua after the Exodus and king Saul, (about 400 years) Israel was ruled by a succession of "Judges" as recorded in the book of Judges.  The fact that Israel was ruled under a theocracy using Judges and prophets does not make it less of nation-state that one ruled by kings.  Indeed, according to the last of the "Judges", the prophet Samuel actually gave an inspired speech where he plainly told them that such a change in the form of Israel's government to monarchy was a backward step - it would be a means for degrading the nation.  See 1 Sam 8.

Unfortunately, Samuel's prophecies proved correct (see the appalling parade of very sinful kings in the books of Kings and Chronicles).  However, before the Israelite monarchies, Israel was still a nation-state for about 400 years earlier.

Thus, there was no "delay" as the OP suggests.

Comment: We might also add in God's reaction in 1 Samuel ch7 v7; "When did I ever ask you for one?" As long as Israel was a loose confederation of tribes, still half-nomad at heart, there was no need for a Temple, and the necessary power and wealth was not avaailable.

Comment: @StephenDisraeli - good point.